# All Parent-Child relationships Vue Components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

How to get all Parent-Child relationships of Vue Components in a project?
Either command line or console.log is OK.

Desired output:

```
├── rootpage
│   ├── componentA
│   │   ├── componentD
│   │   ├── componentF
│   ├── componentB
│   │   ├── componentD
│   │   ├── componentG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to make use of one of the JS parsers to do this. You'll probably also have to integrate it with `vue-loader` in order to extract the script block.

https://esprima.org/

https://github.com/acornjs/acorn

Comment: That sounds hard.

Comment: Yes, writing parsers is hard. @mira